# Validation form with optional fields react-hook-forms

Tags: react-native, expo, react-hook-form

I'm trying to handle a form composed by two parts, one fixed and the other one that gets displayed by a switch.

To handle the forms I'm using `react-hook-form`.

I defined a validation scheme in the file validation.ts inside the constants folder.
About the optional part I defined a sub-object but it doesn't work and it gives a compile time error.
Because of this I opted for the solution you'll find in the link at the bottom of the page

Although I defined the optional input fields inside the validation file, they don't get recognized when I press the submit button.

How can I fix this problem?

At this [link](https://snack.expo.io/@foobanizer137/validation-error) you can find a working example of the problem.

Comment: can you show the `compile time error` you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is with your components/Form component, it has this line

```js
// components/Form.tsx
return child.props.name
      ?  .... : child;
```

What you have done here is ignoring all child components without the `name` prop,
where as when rendering the component what you did was rendered them inside `<></>`, use below alternative instead.

```js
// in App.tsx
{isEnabled ? <Input name="trailerPlate" placeholder="Targa rimorchio" /> : <></>}
{isEnabled ? <Input name="trailerEnrolment" placeholder="Immatricolazione rimorchio" /> : <></>}
```

Still the validation won't because you need to register the components and your current `useEffect` code doesn't account for change in number of input fields.
Use below code instead

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    ....
    ....
  }, [
      register, 
      Array.isArray(children) ? 
           children.filter(child => child.props.name).length : 0
     ]
);
```

We are using the count of child components with `name` prop as a trigger for useEffect.

And finally you also have to `unregister` the fields when you toggle the switch,
below is a sample code, feel free to change it according to your preference.

```js
const { handleSubmit, register, setValue, errors, unregister, clearErrors } = useForm<VehicleForm>();

const toggleSwitch = () => {
  if (isEnabled) {
    unregister('trailerEnrolment');
    unregister('trailerPlate');
  }
  clearErrors();
  setIsEnabled(prev => !prev)
};
```

Feel free to upvote if I was helpful.

Comment: The only problem I encounter with your solution is this: if I enable the switch and fill in all the inputs if I then disable the switch again, the validation errors on the first fields are still shown. The same thing if I first fill in the fields and then enable the switch.

Comment: I update the `snack` so that you can directly see the problem that persists me